# NodeJS with Mongoose - pragmatically add url to image retrieved with find()

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following Mongoose schema:

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    },
    _imageId: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'files'
    }]
});
```

When I retrieve data from the database using the function findOne() in this way

```
getById: function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, user) {
        getProfileImage(req, user, function(user) {
            return res.status(200).send({
                msg: 'User retrieved successfully',
                data: user
            });
        });
    });
}
```

I get an array of image, but only with their id, so I have to manually add the URL using the function getProfileImage.

Is there a way using Mongoose to pragmatically add the URL?

EDIT:

I add the implementation of getProfileImage

```
var getProfileImage = function(req, user, callback) {
    if(user && user._imageId.length > 0) {
        user.set('profileImage', req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + '/image/get/' + user._imageId[user._imageId.length - 1], { strict: false });
    }

    callback(user);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes** there is a way, and it doesn't involve storing `_imageId` in the `userSchema`. **It's the other way around**. You need to create a `imageSchema` that stores `_userId` and fetch all images from there.

## Schemas

```
var userSchema = new Schema({
    username: {
        type: String,
    },
    password: {
        type: String,
    },
    email: {
        type: String,
    }
});

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    url: {
        type: String,
    },
    userId: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    }
});
```

## Controller

```
getById: function (req, res) {
    User.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }, function (err, user) {

        // Get images related to the user
        Image.find({userId: req.params.id}, function(err, images) {
            user.images = images;

            return res.status(200).send({
                msg: 'User retrieved successfully',
                data: user
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: It's a good practice to save the URL into the database? I added the implementation of the function getProfileImage. My idea was to save only the ID into the database and add the URL dynamically, so that even if the URL changes, the images URL is still valid

Comment: If an URL changes you csn still update that in your database. And yes this is good practice

Comment: Ok, then I'll do it the way you say. Thank you!